# Using mysql load data infile Relative path error

Tags: c++, mysql, c, linux

```
LINUX MYSQL C API
MYSQL SERVER VERSION IS:5.1.9         
MYSQL CLIENT API VERSION:6.0.2
```

Error is

> Can't get stat of
>   '/usr/local/mysql/var/NetCenter_Cache/FileCahce_HttpDown.Dat'
>   (Errcode: 2)，内容： LOAD DATA INFILE
>   './NetCenter_Cache/FileCahce_HttpDown.Dat' INTO TABLE
>   `data_httpdown_2013-07-24`
>   (`probe_id`,`src_mac`,`dst_mac`,`src_ip`,`dst_ip`,`src_name`,`dst_name`,`dst_equip_type`,`dst_app_id`,`ip_version`,`ip_tunnel`,`src_port`,`dst_port`,`proto_type`,`proto_sub_type`,`operation`,`log_type`,`log_level`,`opstatus`,`rule_id`,`group_id`,`rulekeyword`,`domain`,`url`,`summary`,`content`,`file_name`,`log_time`,`str_time`)

this path is error:

```
/usr/local/mysql/var/NetCenter_Cache/FileCahce_HttpDown.Dat
```

I am using a relative path

```
./NetCenter_Cache/FileCahce_HttpDown.Dat
```

the path is point to

```
/usr/local/netaudit/NetCenter_Service/NetCenter_Release/NetCenter_Cache
```

Why is changed? And I have no problem using an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

That's because `LOAD DATA` is executed by server process (not client) and a current directory for MySql daemon is

```
/usr/local/mysql/var/
```

Therefore use the absolute path to your data file or if for some reason (I can't imagine any) you want it to be relative then build it from

```
`/usr/local/mysql/var/`
```

and not from

```
`/usr/local/netaudit/NetCenter_Service/NetCenter_Release/`
```

Comment: YES ,i want using Relative path.

Comment: Can you explain why? It will always be relative to `/usr/local/mysql/var/` and not your app folder

Comment: What would the effect of using the ~ (home) folder be? Would that look in /home/currentuser or /home/mysql?

Comment: My reason for needing to use a relative path is because I'm loading about a gigabyte of data as part of an install script, and I would prefer not to copy the input files to arbitrary places or make assumptions about the target machine's directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

A decade later, but starting with MySQL version 8, the LOAD DATA statement has an optional LOCAL modifier that does what you're asking.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html